# Как отправить массив по локальной сети?

Tags: c++, сокет

Сейчас сообщения я отсылаю с помощью:

```
void SendToSocket(SOCKET &soc,string &str)
{
    send(soc, str.c_str(), str.size() + 1, 0);//WinSock2.h
}
```

Но таким образом "переправляются" только строки. Как перебросить произвольный массив данных? Типа `int[]`, но так, чтобы они гарантированно пришли по своему порядку и не вычленились оттуда автоматом некоторые знаки(char) при передаче или приёме. Сейчас текст отправляет приложение на c++, а принимает терминал ubuntu через telnet. Достаточно просто отправлять и принимать массив unsigned char вместо string?

Comment: Сокет не отправляет строки, сокет отправляет байты. Передайте адрес массива и длинну в байтах. Что б не было потерь, нужно передавать ещё и длинну.

Comment: @nick_n_a `char p[] = "Welcome!";
 send(client, &p, sizeof(p), 0);` выдаёт ошибку, что `const char(*)` это не `const char*` (речь про `p`). Что я делаю не так?

Comment: В вашем примере `p` - это уже указатель, нужно передавать сразу его, а не `&p`.

Comment: (1) копируете массив из строкового литерала в массив на стеке (2) передаете адрес массива без приведения (3) используете `sizeof` для определения размера массива (4) не проверяете результат `send` @RiotBr3aker Нет, в этом примере `p` не является указателем, это массив.

Comment: @VTT как проверить результат `send`? Клиентского приложения ещё нет.

Comment: `send` возвращает число - количество отправленных байт (которое может быть меньше, чем отправлялось) или код, означающий ошибку

Comment: @VTT полагаю, проще отсеивать битые на стороне клиента, чем через `while (result_send!=0) {send(остаток)}` крутить. другим клиентам тоже "интересно" что-то получать.

Comment: Какие еще битые? При чем тут другие клиенты?

Comment: @VTT, хорошо, `p` - преобразуемая в указатель на массив переменная, с каких пор char[] -> char* требует явного приведения?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker `p` - это массив `char` который может быть неявно приведен в указатель на `char`.  Я нигде не говорил, что "char[] -> char* требует явного приведения", хотя выполнять приведение явно - это хороший тон.

Comment: @VTT, человек спросил, что *почему* у него не работает код, что к "хорошему тону" не относится имхо.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Я ему ответил, почему у него не работает. Заметьте, что в моем ответе (в первом комментарии) нигде не упоминается про то, что необходимо явно приводить массив к указателю на `char`.

Comment: @VTT, человек спросил "почему не работает", одним из ваших ответов было `"...(2) передаете адрес массива без приведения..."`, я не вижу здесь слово "опционально", как и не вижу смысла спорить на эту тему на самом деле. Имхо, в данном вопросе нет необходимости в "хорошем тоне", мы не на codereview.se, тем не менее пусть каждый останется при своем мнении.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Вот как раз таки приведение адреса массива к указателю на `char` может быть выполнено только явно. Собственно на это и ругается компилятор.

Comment: @VTT, что, простите? `char[] -> char*` у человека в примере в комментариях, зачем там явное приведение? `int[] -> char*` да, требует явного каста, но автор не знает, что так можно, в этом то вопрос и состоял, на что вы просто написали "ну, нужно кастить", что неопытного программиста вряд ли поставит на путь истинный.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Дело в том, что он передает не `p`, а `&p`. А в таком случае нужно явное преобразование. Если бы он передавал просто `p`, то ошибки компиляции не было бы, хотя код был бы по-прежнему нерабочим.